# How to show a new file-upload button after uploading?

Tags: javascript, html

I want to have infinite file-upload buttons. Right after I send a file, a new button appears.

How can I do something like:

[image: infinite-file-upload-buttons]

Answer (score 0):

You can add an event listener to the element to listen for changes and set up **createUploadButton** function to trigger whenever the event is delivered.

```
element.addEventListener('change', createUploadButton);
```

Answer (score 0):

The exact answer to your question is bellow:

```js
function makeNewButton() {
  //create an upload button:
  let uploadbtn = document.createElement('input');
  uploadbtn.setAttribute('type', 'file');
  //append it to your document:
  document.body.appendChild(uploadbtn);
  //add an event listener that fires the function again: 
  uploadbtn.addEventListener('change', makeNewButton);
  //make delete element: 
  let deletetext = document.createElement('p');
  deletetext.textContent = 'Delete';
  //append it to your document: 
  document.body.appendChild(deletetext);
  //Add an event listener to remove the original button and the delete link on click:
  deletetext.addEventListener('click', function() {
    uploadbtn.remove();
    deletetext.remove();
  });


}

makeNewButton();
```

Full documentation to the document interface can be found here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document

Handling the files and sending them to the server is a different mater.